# Rails 4: compiling assets dynamically with sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I want to precompile some of my scss files dynamically (at the runtime). In Rails 3 I used to use Sprockets::StaticCompiler like that.

```
env = Rails.application.assets
target = File.join(Rails.public_path, config.assets.prefix)
compiler = Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(env,
                                           target,
                                           config.assets.precompile,
                                           :manifest_path => config.assets.manifest,
                                           :digest => config.assets.digest,
                                           :manifest => digest.nil?)
compiler.compile
```

How should I do it in Rails 4? There is no documentation or anything on internet.

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you found the way to do this in Rails 4+ ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by using the Sass engine to compile my asset and then writing it to the public/assets folder.

```
asset = env.find_asset(self.sass_file_path)

compressed_body = ::Sass::Engine.new(asset.body, {
  :syntax => :scss,
  :cache => false,
  :read_cache => false,
  :style => :compressed
}).render

File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", "assets", self.stylesheet_file(asset.digest)), 'w') { |f| f.write(compressed_body) }
```

Have a look at this article for an example: http://matteodepalo.github.io/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-create-custom-stylesheets-dynamically-with-rails-and-sass/

Comment: Yeah, I know this approach, but it doesn't work with Rails 4.

Comment: Sorry, actually it does work, but I want to precompile assets with Manifest way (default Sprockets way) so that I can use asset helpers and all other stuff.